# DBSCAN clustering Algorithm

Tags: c++, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am trying to clustering my dataset by using this  [Repo](https://github.com/james-yoo/DBSCAN) Why this code print the same data in the input file without make any clustering for it? and when I use another dataset this code does not make any clustering to the data, any help please?

```
void printResults(vector<Point>& points, int num_points)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("Number of points: %u\n"
        " x     y     z     cluster_id\n"
        "-----------------------------\n"
        , num_points);
    while (i < num_points)
    {
          printf("%5.4lf %5.4lf %5.4lf: %d\n",
                 points[i].x,
                 points[i].y, points[i].z,
                 points[i].clusterID);
          ++i;    }}
```

Comment: This is C++, not C.

Comment: Poor C++, but yes, C++.

Comment: OK, but any help please?!

Comment: This code It doesn't do anything interesting like cluster data. All it does is print out results computed or data loaded elsewhere. You're probably looking at the wrong code.

Comment: @user4581301  Actually I need to use DBSCAN in c or c++ so all the Repo on Github have the output like this code!